# In c++,where does List<int>::push_back(int item) deploy the item to?To the stack or to the heap?

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, stl, stack

I am writing a list class to hold a set of integers. It includes a member function "push_back(int item)" to push integers into the back of the list.

### What I am intending to do:

When push_back(1) is executed, I want the computer do two things:
First,initialize an myNode object (on the stack) with an int member valued as 1
Next,push the myNode object to the back of the list

### The problem I meet:

As the code shown below, when push_back() finished,the newNode object disappears because it was build on the stack.But I want it leaves on the stack upon the list object.

### Why I build the object on the stack:

After doing some research I found that the "new" keyword should be avoided if not necessary, and so now I am trying to deploy things on stack.

### So my question is:

1. How to do this in a safe, efficient and elegant way.
2. There's a function list::push_back(int item) in the STL template. I would like to know how it deals with my problem.

### Code:

```
class myNode
{
 myNode* next;
 myNode* before;
 myNode(int item){
 this->item=item;
}
 int item;
}
class myList
{
 myNode* headNode;
 myNode* lastNode;

 void push_back(int item)
 {
  //here,the newNode is on the stack and it would disappear after the function ends
  myNode* newNode=&myNode(item);

 //doing other stuff
 lastNode->next = newNode;
 newNode->before = lastNode;
 newNode->next = headNode;

 //renew the lastNode
 lastNode=newNode;
...
 }

}

void main(){
myList lst;
lst.push_back(1);
lst.push_back(2);
...
}
```

### Complement:

As a noob, everything I'm assuming could be wrong, such as avoiding "new" keywords in the push_back(). So feel free if you think any part of it should be revised totally.
C++ is mind-blowing, thanks for you all in advance, salute o7!

Comment: @bruno Did you mean that in STL template all nodes of the list are deployed on the heap?I am trying to read the STL code but failed /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: I haven't used `new` in 10 years.  I use standard C++ library objects which use `new` on my behalf but not me using it directly.  Objects like vector, list, queue, deque, map, unique_ptr, shared_ptr, string.

Comment: If you are reinventing the linked list, you should be using dynamic memory allocation (a.k.a. `new`).  Elements on the stack usually disappear after execution leaves the scope (e.g. function).

Comment: As an alternative, you could use an array based linked list.  Instead of pointers, you would use array indices.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for your answer. Did you know how does the STL template deal with this?

Comment: There is no requirement for the exact implementation of the `std::list`.  The common implementation is to place the nodes in dynamic memory; *the C++ language standard has no requirement as to where the data is stored*.  You can supply your own allocation function as well.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks, I would use "new" keyword or  smart pointer to build the list node. But I just found out that the allocator of STL seems to take charge of memory management. At least it is worth having a look.